# Добавление элемента в непустой массив

Tags: java, массивы

Как в **непустой** двумерный массив `int[][] arr` добавить элемент?

Массив был создан следующим образом:

```
int[][] arr = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Comment: Никак, индексы надо знать.

Comment: А как вы другие элементы добавили, раз он непустой?

Comment: ну так что вы там разобрались ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

допустим : 
есть дв-ый массив

```
    int[][] mas = new int[3][3];
```

заполним его случайными числами :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
            mas[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        }
    }
```

выведем в консоль весь массив:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

если у вас где то так, то конечно в массив невозможно что то еще запихнуть, так как массив задается изначально его размер и его размер не изменяется динамически.

ну а если есть дв-ый массив:

```
    int[][] mas = new int[3][3];
```

и вы вручную туда можете засовывать что захотите:
например:

```
    mas[0][0] = 5;
    mas[1][0] = 6;
    mas[2][0] = 10;
    mas[1][1] = 5;
    mas[1][2] = 7;
    mas[2][0] = 6;
```

выводим:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

получаем :

5   0   0
6   5   7
6   0   0

где хранятся нули,свободно можно поместить любые числа.
Выходит это непустой массив и можно поместить еще что то .

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется изменять размер коллекции, то лучше выбрать другую структуру данных. Если же прямо хочется с массивами - то можно нарезать еще 3 массива и условно "приклеить" их с исходному снизу, справа и с угла, написав класс - обертку, содержащий 4 поля-массива и геттер/сеттер, которые по значению входящего индекса будут определять, с каким из физических массивов работать. это очень по-ООП-шному, инкапсуляция / сокрытие реализации и все такое :) Можно сделать даже, чтобы эти классы-обертки можно было вкладывать друг в друга - таким образом мы получаем абстракцию бесконечно расширяемого массива с доступом за О(1), физическая реализация которого будет разбросана по памяти / куче, но кого это волнует (кроме буквоедов, говорящих про промахи кеша и прочую низкоуровневую прелесть), главное же ООП и абстракция :)